# How does Cordova (Meteor)'s cdvfile:// work?

Tags: file, cordova, meteor

I'm using Cordova's fileTransfer (real device: Android 5.0, Cordova 5.2 built-in Meteor)

```
onSuccess: function(entry)
     console.log(entry.toInternalURL);
}
```

entry.toInternalURL, prints:

> cdvfile://localhost/files/my_file.png

However when I try to load the image in my html (Meteor template) by:

```
 <img src='cdvfile://localhost/files/my_file.png' />
```

I tried also with meteor.local and /persistent variants with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dragonmnl,

To load an image in the webview, you would use the *relative path* not the *absolute path*. This goes for all Cordova implementations. If your image is store somewhere else (somewhere not below your `www` directory), then one solution is to convert it into base64 and use [data:URI](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)

Comment: yes, I ended up by using a canvas "hack" ( https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/ ). I tried the relative path way but I can't figure out **which** is the right relative path. Any idea? (for the future)

Comment: Google: [absolute path vs. relative path](https://www.google.com/search?q=absolute+path+vs.+relative+path). This looks good: *Computer Hope - [Absolute path](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/a/absopath.htm)* and [this](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/) --- One more thing that might help. You were using the ***absolute path** of the system* - in your examples. The easiest *relative path* example is an image (file) that is in the same directory as the webpage. I think the links provide more good examples. Best of Luck

Comment: I know what a relative path is. but I don t know how to determine where the files are actually stored since i tried all possible combinations; even navitating in the phone itself

Comment: If you put the images in the same directory as the webpage (usually index.html), then they are relative to each other. If you make a directory called `images/` and put your images in that directory, then your HTML element would be `<img src="images/image.jpg">`. In this case, `images/` is in the same directory as your `index.html`, so the`image.jpg` is stored in a relative directory. -- If you instead wrote, `<img src="cdvfile://project/www/images/image.jpg">`, then you are using the *absolute path* Best of Luck